# CakePHP 3 "Controller class XYZ could not be found." only on production server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a separate AppController for an external API to my site.
I can connect to the API just fine using Postman on my local development machine, but once I move the files to the test site or production site, I get 404 errors like "Controller class Users could not be found."

```
{
    "message": "Controller class Users could not be found.",
    "url": "/api/tv/users/index",
    "code": 404,
    "file": "/var/www/html/site/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ControllerFactory.php",
    "line": 100
}
```

Ubuntu 16.04, Apache, PHP 7.

The code and environment on all servers (local dev, test, and production) should be the same, yet it only works on the local machine. I don't even know what code to post but here's some:

Test code Api/TV/UsersController:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api\TV;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->set([
            'message' => 'Why wont you work?',
            '_serialize' => [
               'message'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Router::prefix('api', function(RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/v2', [
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login',
        '_method' => 'GET'
    ]);

    ...

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Router::prefix('api/v3', function(RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

Router::prefix('api/tv', function(RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

As you can see I have several different API's on different prefixes. Only the last one isn't working (except locally).

I'm at my wit's end here. I *know* the answer is staring me right in the face but I need someone else to point it out for me.

Comment: Even though the problem seems somewhat obvious, it's always helpful if you post information about the different systems (OS, PHP, Server, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parts of your prefixes (separated by `/`) are being inflected using `Inflector::camelize()`, which means `api/tv` becomes `Api/Tv` for the filesystem lookup, and `Api\Tv` for the namespace lookup, so your path and your namespace are wrong, as `Tv` won't match `TV` on case sensitive filesystems.

Long story short, rename your `TV` folder and namespace part to `Tv`.

Comment: See, I told you it would be something simple. Thanks! I still don't understand why it works on my dev environment though. Same operating system and server setup.